# Apply mysql stored procedure on a table column

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I have a mysql stored procedure which accepts a variable and returns a result (the result is produced by a query):

```
mysp (var1) => col1,col2
```

I want to feed the variable from a table to produce an enhancement query such :

table1 => colA,colB,var1

```
select colA,colB, mysp (var1) from table1
```

is that possible ?

Comment: You can make a function which is a stored procedure that returns a value. It looks like you want to return two values, though. That can't be done.

Comment: my sp returns the result of a query

Answer (score 0):

IMHO possible options are:

1. Move `select` to your stored procedure if possible and return final result set;
2. From your SP mysp create and populate temp table. Call procedure. Then join temp table in your select. *Note: Temp tables have session scope.*